# no block given yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block

So executing this gives me back an error:

`no block given (yield)`

Well never had a deep look at blocks in ruby, which seems to be an issue in here. If you have a better solution please provider, otherwise I wanted to find a workaround for the this legacy code...

```
  def tab_groupings
    result = at_a_glance_grouping
    result += rating_grouping if @domain_context.include_ratings and (controller.controller_name !='rewards_credit_cards')
    result += specific_tab_groupings
    result        
  end

  def at_a_glance_grouping
    result = [[:at_a_glance, yield]]
    product_type = controller.controller_name == 'fairfax' ? @product_type_helper[:controller] : controller.controller_name
    result[0][1].insert(0, :overall_rating) if @domain_context.include_ratings and (product_type !='rewards_credit_cards')
    result
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

`yield` is used to execute a block that you pass to the method, and then you do something with the result of that call.

Your method `at_a_glance_grouping` therefore expects you to pass a block to it... which it will then execute on the following line (where you use `yield`)

You don't pass any blocks to `at_a_glance_grouping` in the first line of `tab_groupings`, and therefore ruby rightfully complains.

What are you trying to achieve with the `yield` ?

Do you really need it at all?
If not - then just remove it.

If sometimes you *do* pass a block to this method, then you need to check for that before calling yield eg:

```
 result = [[:at_a_glance, yield]] if block_given?
```